# In Spring Boot, write mongo query to get records of specific fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

We have multiple application and databases. From one of our application, we have to connect to another application database and using mongo query, we have to retrieve records of only few select fields.

We have written the mongo query in spring boot and and tried to retrieve records of only few selected fields.

We are able to establish connection with other database but query to retrieve only few selected fields records is not working. Instead it is returning records of all fields.

We are expecting to get only few select columns data but instead getting records of all fields. We are trying below code:

Mongo Query (Working in Mongo DB)

```
db.collection.find({}, { "_id": 1, "agentName": 1 } )
```

In Spring boot, same query is not working. Below function is for reference:

```
public JsonResponse getDataOfFields(String table, List\<String\> column ) {
String query = "{}";
StringBuilder fieldsToInclude = new StringBuilder("{ ");
for (String fieldName : column) {
fieldsToInclude.append("'").append(fieldName).append("': 1, ");
}
fieldsToInclude.delete(fieldsToInclude.length() - 2, fieldsToInclude.length());
fieldsToInclude.append(" }");
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(query, fieldsToInclude.toString());  
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoTemplate.getDb();
MongoCollection\<Document\> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(table);
List\<Document\> foundEntries = new ArrayList\<\>();
FindIterable\<org.bson.Document\> resultIt = collection.find(basicQuery.getQueryObject());
resultIt.iterator().forEachRemaining(foundEntries::add);
return new JsonResponse(foundEntries, JsonResponse.RESULT_SUCCESS, JsonResponse.STATUS_200);  
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks